# OpenCV Python Executable Error When accessing camera

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, camera, pyinstaller

So basically I was making an **OpenCV python script** that takes a quick picture and exits. But when I try to make it an **executable** file with **pyinstaller**, it gives me this **error:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32api.py", line 18, in <module>
      File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
      File "pywintypes.py", line 105, in <module>
      File "pywintypes.py", line 38, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    ImportError: Module 'pywintypes' isn't in frozen sys.path ['C:\\Users\\Zack\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI109042\\base_library.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Zack\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI109042\\lib-dynload', 'C:\\Users\\Zack\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI109042']
```

Here is my code:

```
import cv2

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

return_value,image = camera.read()
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imwrite('test.jpg',image)

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm on Windows 10

Comment: You need cv2.waitKey(0) or for some time duration after cv2.imshow()

Comment: @fm42. He wanted a quick picture and to exit immediately.. So basically, you don't need watKey and imshow.

Comment: My mistake. I thought for some odd reason he was complaining that it was quitting unexpectantly.

Comment: It is pyinstaller. He wanted to do something with it.